# Why isn’t a string resetting when I recall a method as part of an error check?

Tags: c#, error-handling, console-application

As a beginner in c#, I’ve been making some simple console apps. In one, I have a simple game to solve a computer-generated number code. For each attempt at solving the code, the user enters 5 digits in the form of an input string. The issue is with the error checking, and I’ve put together a simple section of code that shows the problem. If I enter 5 digits, say 12345, the code passes through the errorCheck() and is displayed correctly. If instead, I press a random key, say “a”, the error is recognised, and I can enter again. But this time if I enter a valid number, the output will be “a”.

What I am trying to do is reject an invalid input and replace with a valid one that can be passed to the rest of the program.

Why is this code not working the way I expected?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ErrorCheck
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {           
            string code=enterCode();
            errorCheck(code);
            Console.WriteLine(code);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    
    private static string enterCode()
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter code ");
            string code = Console.ReadLine();
            return code;
        }

        private static void errorCheck(string code)
        {
            bool valid = true;
            int number;
            valid = Int32.TryParse(code, out number);
            if (number > 99999) valid = false;
            if (number < 0) valid = false;
            if (valid == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a valid code");
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to try again");
                Console.ReadLine();
                enterCode();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read: [Tutorial: Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022), it's only a 21 minutes of your time, but saves much more time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "code" you specify in errorCheck does not get passed to your main function.
Inside of erroCheck you call enterCode again, but this doesn't assign it to anything, so the variable "code" in main remains the same as it was on the failed attempt.

I'm not sure if you know about do-while loops already, but it may be a good idea to rely on a while loop and basically do something like this:

```cs
string code;
do
{
    code = enterCode();
} while (errorCheck(code) == false) // or !errorCheck(code)

// Should return true or false depending on success
private static bool errorCheck() 
{
    ...
}
```

That way, no matter how many times the code is wrong, it will keep checking. With the additional benefit of fixing your bug in the process.

Some additional unwanted advice: method names in C# should start with an upper case letter LikeThis().
Good luck on your coding journey!

Comment: Mind: `errorCheck` should take a string parameter,  of course.

Comment: Your code block works well and has allowed me to complete my first console application. I think I get the reasoning why my initial logic was incorrect but will ponder some more. And of course I'm only too happy to be corrected on the syntax of the methods.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Spectre.Console](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spectre.Console/0.45.1-preview.0.43) NuGet package makes this easy. Install the package and you can create a method that handles obtaining a number within a specific range as per below. The result is an `int` so if a `string` is desired use `answer.ToString()`

```
internal partial class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int answer = GetNumber();
        Console.WriteLine(answer);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private const int Max = 99999;
    public static int GetNumber() =>
        AnsiConsole.Prompt(
            new TextPrompt<int>("[white on blue]Enter a number:[/]")
                .PromptStyle("cyan")
                .ValidationErrorMessage("[red]Must be integer[/]")
                .Validate(value => value switch
                {
                    < 0 or > Max => ValidationResult.Error($"[red]Must be greater than 0 and less than {Max}[/]"),
                    _ => ValidationResult.Success(),
                }));
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm intrigued but will come back to add on packages when I've got the absolute basics under my belt.